# How to render a ShapeTemplate without a contentitem?

Tags: model-view-controller, orchardcms

im new to orchard and my brain is burning because of the MVCSHD model
(Model View Controller Shape Handler Driver)

From Orchard docu:

> Shapes are dynamic data models that use shape templates to make the data visible to the user in the way you want. Shape templates are fragments of markup for rendering shapes. Examples of shapes include menus, menu items, content items, documents, and messages.

I would like to display a Shape Template and provide a Model into the view that is not a ContentPart and got no ContentItem.

Because i want to create this Model in the Controller (or in the driver later if i get this working finally).
The content of the model is dynamicly created.

in the Controller this is not working:

```
        TestThingie testThingie = new TestThingie (5);
        _orchardServices.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(testThingie,"Summary");
```

Because testTingie does not have a contentItem...
Is there any other way to display a shapeTemplate with a Model? What am i missing here?

Is it just me or is it kinda impossible to gain furhter Information about how all this stuff is about to work out of the Documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BuildDisplay` method is for crafting the display shapes of a given content item. You don't have a content item, so you cannot use that method.

What you can do however is use the dynamic `Display`:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    TestThingie testThingie = new TestThingie(5);

    return View(myShape);
}
```

Then in your Views/MyControllerName/MyAction.cshtml:

```
@Display.MyShape(Thingie: Model.TestThingie)
```

And in your MyShape.cshtml:

```
@{
    TestThingie thingie = Model.Thingie;
}
```